# perl's open() fails sometimes when file name ends with whitespace

Tags: perl, io

I'm facing a problem with Perl's open() function. It is related to the files whose names end with whitespace. If I use open() with 2 arguments (filehandle and filename) and filename ends with whitespace, open() fails. Error message says that file cannot be found, although file exists. No such thing happen when opening mode is specified, e.g., if I state explicitly that file is opened for reading. Here is some sample code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = '/tmp/test_with_ending_space ';

open WRITE, ">", $file or die "open with mode got error: $!";
print WRITE "my open() test\n";
close WRITE;

# open() with mode
open READ, "<", $file or die "open without mode got error: $!";
while (<READ>) {
    print;
}
close READ;

# open() without mode
open READ1, $file or die $!;
while (<READ1>) {
    print;
}
close READ1;
```

And here is the output from such code:

```
marius@mariusm-PC:~/perl$ ./test.pl
my open() test
open without mode got error: No such file or directory at ./test.pl line 21.
```

No such things happen with "usual" filenames, i.e., when filenames end with some other character.

Any ideas if this is a known problem? If yes, is there a way how to workaround it?

And just in case, before you start telling me "be nice, specify mode and tell your open() how to open the file". Unfortunately, this issue is present in some core modules, e.g., IO::File::open() (that's where I got stuck originaly). Last call in this function is `open($fh, $file)`, i.e., it calls native open() without any particular mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's documented in [open](http://p3rl.org/open)

> The filename passed to the one- and two-argument forms of
>                  open() will have leading and trailing whitespace deleted

Read the following paragrpahs for more details.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I went through that doc before but somehow that part escaped from my view.

Comment: @choroba: Well spotted. That's not something that arises a lot in practice and it's not something I knew. It's yet another reason to evangelise the three-parameter form of open (assuming the implication that anything *other* than *"one- and two-argument forms of open"* don't have this problem).

Comment: Also, since his problem originated in using [`IO::File`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::File) with the one parameter form of `->new` which falls back to the 2 parameter form of `open`, one should aim to use the 2 parameter form of the constructor.

Answer (score -2):

@choroba gave the "why", but you also asked for a workaround.

Well, this is VERY kludgey, but if you're desperate and can't change the `open()` calls, this will work.  First, detect if the filename ends with whitespace (I assume you can handle that).  If it does, create a temp symlink to the file (without trailing whitespace!), and open the symlink.

WFM in my (old) Solaris 2.6 box.

Comment: Changing `open READ1, $file` to `open READ1, '<', $file` is a much better "workaround" than that! (`open READ1, "$file\0"` probably works too, but that's evil!)

Comment: @ikegami: This solution carries the proviso that the OP *"can't change the `open()` calls"*

Comment: @jimtut: Have you checked that `symlink` doesn't have the same problem? It's certainly something you should have made sure of before posting an off-beat answer. I don't know either way, and am using an Android tablet while I travel so I can't check.

Comment: @Borodin, thank you for pointing out that I was in fact trying to help the op's scenario of being unable to change the underlying `open`.  However, the symlink (without trailing whitespace) does in fact work (just verified), so I don't think I deserved the downvote.

Comment: He doesn't need to change the underlying open. Just use `open` instead of `IO::File->new`. Or specifiy the third arg to `IO::File->new`.